# Compare new sheet to master sheet and extract the unique rows of the new sheet on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master sheet that contains information that I have to use. Every month, I would have a new sheet that will contain rows that are present in the master sheet and also some new unique rows. I want to extract the new and unique rows of the new sheet as I have to make some edits to it before adding them on to the master sheet. How can I do so? Below is an example of the sheets:

Master sheet:

| ID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 1234 |
| 2 | BB | 2345 |
| 3 | CC | 3456 |
| 4 | DD | 4567 |
| 5 | EE | 5678 |
| ... | ... | ... |

New Sheet:

| ID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BB | 2345 |
| 4 | DD | 4567 |
| 5 | EE | 5678 |
| 6 | FF | 6789 |
| 7 | GG | 7890 |

Desired output:

| ID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | FF | 6789 |
| 7 | GG | 7890 |

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print(new_sheet.loc[~new_sheet['ID'].isin(master_sheet['ID']))
```

Comment: This seems to show me unique values across the whole master sheet (ie ID 2,4,5,6,7). I only want the new values from the new sheet that are not in the master sheet. (ie just ID 6 and 7)

Comment: @jezrael Is it a dupe?

Comment: @jezrael Ah yeah sorry, will wiki